# How recognize weekday depending on entry date

Tags: r

I have a simple question, but I wanted to know how to do it: I have a database and two input data (`dmda` and `DTest`):

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(date = c("2021-06-23","2021-06-24","2021-06-30","2021-07-01"),
       DTT= c("Hol","Hol","Hol",0),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Thursday","Wednesday","Thursday"),
       Category = c("ABC","FDE","ABC","FDE"),
       DR01 = c(4,1,2,3), DR02= c(4,2,0,2),DR03= c(9,5,0,1),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,2),DR05 = c(5,4,0,2)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
   
  dmda<-"2021-07-01"
    DTest <-"0"

df2<-df1%>%
group_by(Category,Week, DTT) %>%
summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), median),.groups = 'drop')

> df2
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  Category Week      DTT    DR01  DR02  DR03  DR04  DR05
  <chr>    <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ABC      Wednesday Hol       3     2   4.5     4   2.5
2 FDE      Thursday  0         3     2   1       2   2  
3 FDE      Thursday  Hol       1     2   5       4   4
```

If I want to make an `if` condition I can do it like this:

```
if(any(df2$DTT == DTest & df2$Week == "Thursday" , na.rm = TRUE)) {
....
}
```

Now my doubt is that I didn't want to use `df2$Week == "Thursday"` but rather use `dmda` that was defined. In other words, is there any way, from the date I chose in `dmda`, for the code to identify what day of the week it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert the 'dmda' to `Date` class and extract the weekday with `format` (`%A`) - which is specified in the `?strptime` documentation

> %A - Full weekday name in the current locale. (Also matches abbreviated name on input.)

```
wkday <- format(as.Date(dmda), "%A")
wkday
[1] "Thursday"
```

and then use that in the `if` loop

```
if(any(df2$DTT == DTest & df2$Week == wkday , na.rm = TRUE)) {
....
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution @akrun. But I have a brief problem because in another database I have, I don't have `Thursday` in Week as in the system, but `Thursday day`. It's a way they did it. Then it won't identify because `Thursday` is used in the system and in my database is  `Thursday day`, right?. Do you know if there is any solution to solve this?

Comment: @Antonio If that is the case can you do `wkday <- sub("\\s+.*", "", format(as.Date(dmda), "%A"))` i..e after the `format`, just remove the space followed by any characters with `sub` and now it should match with `DTT` or other option is `grepl`